# Adding maven repository to nexus automatically

Tags: java, maven, nexus

Too often, I find myself adding proxy repositories to nexus.
Is there a tool that can automatically scan my poms and add the entries from the  section to nexus?

Comment: I don't understand why there is a need. My opinion: I install Maven several times (and add in the configuration repositories); I install Nexus (in my case Artifactory) once and generate from there the Maven section for repositories; I create POMs a lot of times, and I don't add there repository information (if possible).

Comment: For dynamic projects with many technologies there is a great usage for it. and I'm not the only one asking:http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/is-there-a-tool-to-automatically-add-proxies-td511761.html

Answer (score 2):

First there is no such tool to do that automatically. Furthermore there shouldn't be repositories configured in the pom, cause that's not best practice im Maven.

It should be possible to create such a tool. By using the [Aether library](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/AETHER/Home) which can help you to extract information out of the pom and with some basic http stuff put that result into a configuration of Nexus.